# eclipse won't work when trying to run php?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on my first *hello world* project in eclipse, but when i run it, it opens eclipse' built in web browser, and gives me  404 error. I haven't set up any server or anything, I just used the defaults that came with the php plugin for eclipse. The URL that it brings me to is: http://localhost/helloworld/newfile.php what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have a server, you can't run a PHP script.  You need to have a web server like Apache with the PHP plugin.  Try using something like [WAMPServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) - its an all-in-one install that gives you the servers and MySQL to boot.  Once the servers are installed, you can  run your scripts there by pointing your Eclipse project at the servers document root.  [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is another server bundle like WAMPServer.

Alternaively, here's a tutorial for getting started without either of those options: http://www.tigerheron.com/article/2008/01/eclipse-and-php.

Comment: I have a server, but how do I use it with eclipse if I am running eclipse on my windows pc?

Comment: You can run it externally as normal, but just point your Eclipse project at the document root on the server.  Then you can edit files live on the server.

Comment: Create a new project in Eclipse; when asked for the location, navigate to the server's document root.  That's where all your project files will now reside,

Answer (score 1):

I found this when looking for how to map a network drive in order to open the eclipse workspace through an ftp, and I thought this might help:
    http://www.netdrive.net/